# How can I prevent thunderbird to start if the profile is missing?

Tags: thunderbird

I don't want thunderbird to start if a profile (folder) is missing. This works in my "old" thunderbird installation  (68.10.0), however on a new machine it automatically creates the missing profile (folder).

My old thunderbird installation behaves like this:

If the profile is not there, it does not start, instead it shows the following message:
"Your Thunderbird profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible."
And this is the desired behavior.

How can I prevent thunderbird to automatically create the profile folder path and create an new profile if the path is missing?

More precisely: How can I prevent thunderbird to start if the profile is missing?

Answer (score 0):

ref: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_%28Thunderbird%29

**Profile Data protection**
"    You may need to edit the Thunderbird shortcut to use -P to specify the profiles location. "